# CSS tree structure 1-4-3

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Currently I am trying to make a v-for loop of list items and then want to create a tree structure of this list item. But not sure how I can fix the basic vertical 1-4-3 column like this.

[image]

```html
<ul class="three">
  <li class="unordered-list">A</li>
  <li class="unordered-list">B</li>
  <li class="unordered-list">C</li>
  <li class="unordered-list">D</li>
  <li class="unordered-list">B-1</li>
  <li class="unordered-list">B-2</li>
  <li class="unordered-list">B-3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit complex with flexbox, especially if you're trying to build a dynamic loop.

If you're looking for a CSS only solution, it *may* be more feasible with CSS Grid.

Here's a concept to consider, featuring the `grid-template-areas` property:

```css
.three {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  
  grid-template-areas:
  
     ".  C  ."
     ".  .  B-1"     
     "A  B  B-2"     
     ".  .  B-3"
     ".  D  ."
     ".  E  .";
}

.A   { grid-area: A; }
.B   { grid-area: B; }
.C   { grid-area: C; }
.D   { grid-area: D; }
.E   { grid-area: E; }
.B-1 { grid-area: B-1; }
.B-2 { grid-area: B-2; }
.B-3 { grid-area: B-3; }

.unordered-list {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="three">
  <li class="unordered-list A">A</li>
  <li class="unordered-list B">B</li>
  <li class="unordered-list C">C</li>
  <li class="unordered-list D">D</li>
  <li class="unordered-list E">E</li>  
  <li class="unordered-list B-1">B-1</li>
  <li class="unordered-list B-2">B-2</li>
  <li class="unordered-list B-3">B-3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is very clean, chapeau!

Comment: Is there also a concise way to draw the css lines that connects the list items?

Comment: I would suggest that you post a new question for that part of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Michal Benjamin I have a flexbox solution :)
I agree though, that this might be what grid is actually designed for.

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

main {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  height: 6rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mainUl {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;

  justify-content: space-between;

  align-items: center;
}

.ul2 li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 7rem;
}

.ul2 li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 7rem;
}

.ul2 li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.ul3 {
  margin-bottom: 9rem;
}

.ul3 li {
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <ul class="mainUl">
        <div class="col1">
          <div class="box">
            <p>A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <ul class="ul2">
            <li>
              <div class="box"><p>C</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="box"><p>B</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="box"><p>D</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="box"><p>E</p></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
          <ul class="ul3">
            <li>
              <div class="box"><p>B1</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="box"><p>B2</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="box"><p>B3</p></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/battleaxe/fb0urm7z/